# Swift Error on mutable state as let constant

Tags: swift, swiftui

I have simple codeable json. I am using for each loop for iteration, here I comparing the product based on id. If the id exists, then it should increase the quantity otherwise add the item and I am using this function in view as well. But I am getting following error. **Left side of mutating operator isn't mutable; 'quantity' is a 'let' constant**. I have tried to use mutating key word before the function and also change the struct let to var but it did not help.

Here is my codeable json.

```swift
import Foundation
// MARK: - Welcome
struct ProductData: Codable, Hashable {
    let carts: [Cart]
}

// MARK: - Cart
struct Cart: Codable, Hashable {
    let id: Int
    let products: [Product]
}

// MARK: - Product
struct Product: Codable, Hashable, Identifiable {
    let id: Int
    let title: String
    let price, quantity, total: Int
    let discountPercentage: Double
    let discountedPrice: Int
    let thumbnail: String
}
```

Here is my function.

```swift
class Order: ObservableObject {
    
    @Published var product = [Product]()
    @Published private(set) var productTotal: Int = 0
    
    func add(item: Product) {
        var exists = false
        product.forEach { product in
            if product.id == item.id {
                exists = true
                product.quantity += 1 // error on this line
            }
        }
        if !exists {
            product.append(item)
        }
    }
}
```

Here is the screenshot of the error.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all please name `product` in plural form `products`.

```
@Published var products = [Product]()
```

There are two problems:

1. You have to declare `quantity` in `Product` as variable

   ```
    var quantity: Int
   ```
2. Index variables/elements in loops are immutable. In fact they are immutable for a good reason: Due to value semantics the index element is a **copy** of the array item which won't modify the original item in the array.

But you don't need a loop at all. Try to get the index of the item in the array. If the item exists increase `quantity` otherwise append the item. `products[index]` modifies the array in place

```
func add(item: Product) {
   if let index = products.firstIndex(where: {$0.id == item.id }) {
       products[index].quantity += 1
   } else {
       products.append(item)
   }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Your `Product` has `quantity` property as a constant, you cannot modify it this way. Change quantity to `var` then iterate through the product array with a for loop. `forEach` within array of value type would create a constant copy inside the closure.

```swift
struct Product: Codable, Hashable, Identifiable {
    ...
    var quantity: Int
}

class Order: ObservableObject {
    ...
    func add(item: Product) {
        for i in 0..<product.count where product[i].id == item.id {
            product[i].quantity += 1
            return
        }
        product.append(item)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The object passed into an iterator closure is always `let` declared so you can't modify it if it's a value type, there are several ways to solve this but here is one that I think should work fine for this situation.

First change from `let` to `var` in your struct

```
var price, quantity, total: Int
```

Then add a mutating function to update the quantity, the advantage to using a function here is that you might want to change other things as well like calculating and updating the `total` value

```
mutating func increase(quantity: Int) {
    self.quantity += quantity
}
```

Then in the `add` function we first make a mutable copy of the object if we find a match and then update the quantity using the new function

```
func add(item: Product) {
    if let index = product.firstIndex(where: { $0.id == item.id }) {
        var copy = item
        copy.increase(quantity: 1)
        product[index] = copy
    } else {
        product.append(item)
    }
}
```

Note the use of `firstIndex(where:)` so we get an index in the array instead of the element so that we can replace the old object with our new calculated object.

Comment: On a side note, I find it a little odd that the `quantity` and `total` properties belongs to `Product` instead of being in a separate type.